# What is the value of the mean of these numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $13^{a+b}=13^{xy}=13^{13}$, what is the mean of $a, b, x$ and $y$?

What I tried: the mean is $\frac{a+b+x+y}{4}$. One can infer that $a+b=13$ so that the mean is $\frac{13+x+y}{4}$. I don't know what to do from here. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Maybe $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be positive integers. Then since $13$ is prime, $x+y=14$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ah ok, that's probably it. Remains weird that they  didn't mention that in the question (this was an question from a GRE practice test book).

Comment: I hope that *real* GRE questions are more precise!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Me too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x y =13$,
This tells you that $x$ and $y$ can only be 1 and 13 in some order.

Assuming, of course, that $x$ and $y$ are positive integers. Otherwise, say if $x$ and $y$ are just real numbers, then you have an infinite number (uncountably so) of solutions!

$m(x) = \frac{13 + x + \frac{13}{x}}{4}$

Comment: You're assuming $x,y$ are natural numbers.

Comment: Aw crap. You're right.

Comment: Thanks, accepted your answer. Would be good to edit @rlartiga's comment into your answer though :)